# What are some good plants to keep around the house to keep my cat away from other plants?

Tags: cats, diet

My cat frequently gets cravings to munch on plants, but as I live in an apartment in a dense urban area currently, she gets less exposure to grass and is eating plant material (namely, gardenia leaves) that make her sick.

Are there specific plants I can keep around my apartment that are both better for her and more tempting than the plants I'd prefer to keep intact?

Answer (score 3):

You could try growing her some [Cat Grass](https://www.cat-world.com.au/catgrass.html), she may or may not *prefer* the cat grass to the other plants however and if she doesn't you'll need to do some training to get her in the habit of directing her urges on to it. The best way to do this will vary depending on your cat's personality but some tricks would be to sprinkle some treats/cat nip over the grass to get her attention or if feasible take the other plants away for a few days to give her no choice and hope that the "habit" forms.